# How can i add weights in a bag of words model in text analysis?

Tags: text-mining, social-network-analysis, feature-engineering

I have a twitter sentiment analysis using bag of word approach from the training set. Now i want to add weights to certain words so that they are considered more important than others.

Comment: The answer to this question depends on what model you are using for your sentiment analysis algorithm. So what model are you using? Naive Bayes, LogReg, Recurrent Net?

Comment: I am using Naive Bayes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to introduce prior counts for words (higher counts for words that are more important) that could be added to the term-document matrix.

An alternative solution is to compute tf-idf features (weights that modify word counts based on frequency) and apply additional weighting to tf-idf with higher weights corresponding to important words.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add weights to rare or infrequent terms, which appear only in few texts, definetly you should use the tf-idf technique, which computes the frequency of each word on all the data set and after that computes a weight of each word in each text.

Another case, if you want to add weights to specific words, you just can modify the tf-idf technique.